# Create a frquency plot of three different categories

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using the categories in the first column

```
category    sex
3   2
2   1
3   1
3   1
3   1
2   1
2   1
3   1
3   1
3   1
3   2
3   1
2   2
3   2
2   1
3   1
1   1
```

How is it possible to produce a frequency plot which will have in the same plot the 3 categories (1,2,3) and will show how many in percentage male and female prefer this category (1=male, 2=female for sex column)?

Comment: we can easily "google it". here some resources: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-frequency-table-for-categorical-data-in-r/

Answer (score 1):

Reshaping the data

```
res <- df %>% 
      group_by(category) %>% 
      summarise(Freq=n())%>% 
      mutate(freq=Freq/sum(Freq))
```

Draw the plot:

```
ggplot(res, aes(x=category, y= freq, fill = Freq, group = freq, label = 
 scales::percent(freq))) + 
  geom_col(position = 'dodge')+
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = .9),    
            vjust = -0.5,    # nudge above top of bar
            size = 10) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

Plot:

[image]

or for the `sex` variable:

Data reshaping:

```
res <- df %>% 
      group_by(sex) %>% 
      summarise(Freq=n())%>% 
      mutate(freq=Freq/sum(Freq))
```

Drawing the plot:

```
ggplot(res, aes(x=as.factor(sex), y= freq, fill = Freq, group = freq, label = scales::percent(freq))) + 
  
  geom_col(position = 'dodge')+
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = .9),    # move to center of bars
            vjust = -0.5,    # nudge above top of bar
            size = 10) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+
  #geom_col(aes(y=freq), stat="identity", position = "dodge")+
  labs(x="Sex", y="Percentage", title="", fill="")+

  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,  face="bold", size=20, color="black")) + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(family="Times", face="bold", size=16, color="black"))+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(family="Times", face="bold", size=16, color="black"))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text( hjust = 1,  face="bold", size=14, color="black") )+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text( hjust = 1,  face="bold", size=14, color="black") )+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  theme(legend.title = element_text(family="Times", color = "black", size = 16,face="bold"),
        legend.text = element_text(family="Times", color = "black", size = 14,face="bold"),
        legend.position="",
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Outcome:

[image]

Or

library(dplyr)

Data shaping:

```
res <- df %>% 
      group_by(category, sex) %>% 
      summarise(Freq=n())%>% 
      mutate(freq=Freq/sum(Freq))
```

Drawing the plot:

```
ggplot(res, aes(x=category, y= freq, fill = as.factor(sex), group = freq, label = scales::percent(freq))) + 
  
  geom_col(position = 'dodge')+
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = .9),    # move to center of bars
            vjust = -0.5,    # nudge above top of bar
            size = 10) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+
  #geom_col(aes(y=freq), stat="identity", position = "dodge")+
  labs(x="Category", y="Percentage", title="", fill="")+
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,  face="bold", size=20, color="black")) + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(family="Times", face="bold", size=16, color="black"))+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(family="Times", face="bold", size=16, color="black"))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text( hjust = 1,  face="bold", size=14, color="black") )+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text( hjust = 1,  face="bold", size=14, color="black") )+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  theme(legend.title = element_text(family="Times", color = "black", size = 16,face="bold"),
        legend.text = element_text(family="Times", color = "black", size = 14,face="bold"),
        legend.position="bottom",
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Outcome:

[image]

Or if you want a stacked bar chart then:

Data shaping:

```
res <- df %>% 
      group_by(category, sex) %>% 
      summarise(Freq=n())%>% 
      mutate(freq=Freq/sum(Freq))
```

Drawing the plot:

```
ggplot(res, aes(x=category, y= freq, fill = as.factor(sex), group = freq, label = scales::percent(freq))) + 
  
  geom_col(position = 'stack')+
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = .0),    # move to center of bars
            vjust = -0.5,    # nudge above top of bar
            size = 10) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+
  scale_colour_discrete( labels = c("1" = "Male", "2" = "Female"))+
  #geom_col(aes(y=freq), stat="identity", position = "dodge")+
  labs(x="Category", y="Percentage", title="", fill="")+
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,  face="bold", size=20, color="black")) + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(family="Times", face="bold", size=16, color="black"))+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(family="Times", face="bold", size=16, color="black"))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text( hjust = 1,  face="bold", size=14, color="black") )+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text( hjust = 1,  face="bold", size=14, color="black") )+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  theme(legend.title = element_text(family="Times", color = "black", size = 16,face="bold"),
        legend.text = element_text(family="Times", color = "black", size = 14,face="bold"),
        legend.position="bottom",
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Outcome:

[image]

Comment: Thank you it is different. I would like to have the category at the frequency and have two bars one for 1 and 2 for every category

Comment: something like this http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_means_and_error_bars_(ggplot2)/figure/unnamed-chunk-6-2.png

Comment: sorry but as I can understand you plot one variable I try to combine both